# run cmd.exe as administrator in a script

Tags: windows, vbscript, runas

I have a script that I need to run as Administrator just as I would right click on cmd.exe and click *Run As Administrator*.

Currently this is what I have:

```
Call WSHShell.Run("cmd.exe /K netdom renamecomputer ... end code")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried using ShellExecute?

RunCmdElevated.vbs

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/k echo test", "", "runas", 1
```

> wscript RunCmdElevated.vbs

gives

> test
>
> C:\Windows\system32>

in a new window. The "1" is the view mode

http://ss64.com/vb/shellexecute.html

Comment: When I do this I get a User Account Control dialog. How do I grab that dialog and click the 'Yes' using SendKeys?